# Help needed in AdventureWorks in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was just playing with adventureworks database in sqlserver. I got stuck in a query.
I wanted to Select all titles from HumanResources.Employee which are either 'Male' or 'Female' but not both.
i.e if title Accountant is Male and Female both I want to leave that title.
I need only those titles where Gender is either Male or Female.

I have done this till yet.

> select distinct(title) from humanresources.employee where gender='M'
>   
>   select distinct(title) from humanresources.employee where gender='F'

Probably a join between these two queries, would work. But If you have any other solution, please let me know.

It is not a homework. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean "not both"? Also, what do you mean by "so that I can get the result"?

Tell me what you are hoping to see in the result.

Comment: Are you asking where all employees with this title are either all Male or all Female?

Comment: I think he means only titles which have only females or only males as title-holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version

```
select title from HumanResources.Employee as t
where gender='M' And Not Exists(select null from HumanResources.Employee as e
                        where gender='F' And e.title =t.title)
Union 

select title from HumanResources.Employee as t1
where gender='F' And Not Exists(select null from HumanResources.Employee as e1
                        where gender='M' And e1.title =t1.title)
order by title
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT t.title
  FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE t
 WHERE t.gender = 'M'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE e
                   WHERE e.gender = 'F'
                     AND e.title = t.title)
UNION ALL
SELECT t.title
  FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE t
 WHERE t.gender = 'F'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE e
                   WHERE e.gender = 'M'
                     AND e.title = t.title)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the the distinct titles issue.  I didn't pick that up.  Removing my response.

Comment: Your query is returning 60 such 'Titles'. :) Please Check it. It is not the correct query.

Comment: The number of titles means nothing - you'll have to provide more information about what issue(s) you believe you have with the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct title FROM humanResources.employee 
WHERE gender = 'M'  and 
  jobtitle not in (select title FROM humanResources.employee  WHERE gender='F') 
union
select distinct title FROM humanResources.employee 
WHERE gender = 'F'  and 
  jobtitle not in (select title FROM humanResources.employee  WHERE gender='M')
```

Comment: This would only get the jobs where the titles were all male, but would not work for female.

Comment: @Irwin: Then I hope you reverse downvotes once things have been corrected.

Comment: Actually I tried after it was changed but it said it was too late.

Answer (score 0):

```
select title
from (
    select distinct title, gender
    from HumanResources.Employee) as temptable
group by title
having count(title) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of variety, I like this one (just for aesthetics)

```
with WomensJobs as
(
    select distinct(Title) title from HumanResources.Employee where Gender='F' 
),
MensJobs as
(
    select distinct(Title) title from HumanResources.Employee where Gender='M'
),
WomenOnlyJobs as
(
    SELECT title from WomensJobs EXCEPT SELECT title from MensJobs
),
MenOnlyJobs as
(
    SELECT title from MensJobs EXCEPT SELECT title from WomensJobs
)
select 'M', title from MenOnlyJobs
UNION 
select 'F', title from WomenOnlyJobs
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(title)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
 WHERE t.gender = 'M'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(t.title)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
 WHERE t.gender = 'F'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT(title)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
 WHERE t.gender = 'F'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(t.title)
  FROM HumanResources.Employee
 WHERE t.gender = 'M'
```

Comment: Most will/should have a knee-jerk reaction to say "don't use DISTINCT when you're using UNION", but it's necessary for the EXCEPT comparison.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. but I am not able to get 'vice president of production' in resultset, It should be there.

Comment: I think the order of operations are missed here. It's being applied as (((M except F) union F) except M) which is logically equivalent to the women-only titles.